Bound of integrand in an improper integral
In the following proof of a Lemma, there are two points that I do not understand.


Lemma. For $x>0$ and $c>0$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} \frac{x^{s+1}}{s(s+1)} d s= \begin{cases}x-1 & \text { if } x \geq 1, \\ 0 & \text { if } x \leq 1 .\end{cases}
$$

Proof. If $x \geq 1$, then $x^{s+1}$ is uniformly bounded for $\operatorname{Re} s \leq c$. We set
$$
D=\{s \in \mathbb{C}:|s| \leq R, \operatorname{Re} s \leq c\},
$$
where $R>1$. If $C$ denotes the oriented boundary of $D$, we have by the Residue Theorem
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_C \frac{x^{s+1}}{s(s+1)} d s=\operatorname{Res}_{s=0} \frac{x^{s+1}}{s(s+1)}+\operatorname{Res}_{s=-1} \frac{x^{s+1}}{s(s+1)}=x-1 .
$$
Part of $C$ is an arc of length at most $2 \pi R$, where the integrand is bounded by $x^{c+1} / R(R-1)$. The contribution of this part converges to zero as $R \rightarrow \infty$. The integral over the straight part of $C$ converges to the improper path integral on the left-hand side of the asserted formula.
If $x \leq 1$, then $x^{s+1}$ is uniformly bounded for $\operatorname{Re} s \geq c$, and we set
$$
D=\{s \in \mathbb{C}:|s| \leq R, \operatorname{Re} s \geq c\} .
$$
This time the integrand has no poles in $D$. The rest of the argument is the same. $\,\,\square$

Here is my question:

In the proof it says that the integrand is bounded (absolutely) by $\frac{x^{c+1}}{R(R-1)}$. I do not get this part. First I thought that the inverse triangle inequality $|x+y|\geq |x|-|y|$ is used, but we have $|s|\leq R$ and I think the denominator has to be made smaller.

Thanks for any help!
